# Delphi Network Printer Access Path

Tags: delphi, zebra-printers, network-printers

I have my original question posted here:

[Delphi Printer Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731528/delphi-printing-using-file-rewrite-function?noredirect=1#comment116383824_65731528)

Now we need to handle one more case of network printer with specific IP say xx.xx.x.x .
How Do we access Network printer from Delphi for Rewrite function?

I did sample app with this code and it works for all printers:

```
  AssignPrn(lOutputFile);
  Rewrite(lOutputFile);

 for liIndex := 0 to lsLines.Count-1 do
    Writeln(lOutputFile, lsLines[liIndex]);

  CloseFile(lOutputFile);
```

On click of f7 on CloseFile(lOutputFile); in sample app, control goes nowhere and printing works.

When I integrated my code in the main application
On click of f7 on CloseFile(lOutputFile) it goes got o Devexpress files and its not printing.

kindly suggest.

Comment: In your other question I showed you how to print with the spooler API, use that!

Answer (score 2):

Windows can access network printers. See the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-a-printer-in-windows-10-cc0724cf-793e-3542-d1ff-727e4978638b).

Once the printer is installed, your application can access that printer just like any other [local] printer.

Use a fully qualified function name: `System.CloseFile(lOutputFile);`